# %in% when vector has unstructured elements

Tags: r

I want to subset a dataframe like

```
ID <- paste(1:10, LETTERS[1:10], sep = "")
var1 <- c(paste(rep("Gene", 4), 1:4, sep = ""), "Gene15 /// Gene11", 
paste(rep("Gene", 5), 6:10, sep = ""))
df <- data.frame("ID" = ID, "var1" = var1)
tomatch <- c(paste(rep("Gene", 10), 2:11, sep = ""))

want <- df[df$var1 %in% 
tomatch, ]
```

But `df$var1` is a vector that contains some elements with single values (e.g. Gene1), and some elements with multiple elements with a separator " /// " (e.g. Gene15 /// Gene11). `tomatch` is a vector of names: `c(Gene1, Gene2, Gene3...)`. 
Thank you.

Comment: No, I want to match any gene that is in `tomatch`. Sorry I edited the example so it is a better representation of the data I have. Thank you.

Comment: You could attack it with regex `df[grepl(sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", paste(tomatch, collapse="|")), df$var1),]` (?) but probably better to arrange the data so that "multiple elements" are not combined within one string.

Comment: I think your example is still not correct,  as both  `"Gene15 /// Gene11"` doesnt have any  match in vector.

Comment: Gene11 should be in both `var1` and `tomatch`. Only one match needs to be true to subset that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
want <- df[sapply(strsplit(df$var1, ' /// '), 
                  function(x) any(x %in% tomatch)), ]
```

want

```
    ID              var1
2   2B             Gene2
3   3C             Gene3
4   4D             Gene4
5   5E Gene15 /// Gene11
6   6F             Gene6
7   7G             Gene7
8   8H             Gene8
9   9I             Gene9
10 10J            Gene10
```